# A simple open-source offline bill management system

Tags: linux, open-source, finance

I want a system to manage the bills I receive at home (water, electricity, etc). I've tried several personal finance management (like [GNUCash](https://www.gnucash.org/)) but they're a bit too complicated, with all the double-entry bookkeeping and such.

Here's the workflow I'd like to use:

- Add a *bill* to a *list of bills* that belong to a given *category*
- Set the *bill* as *payed*, with a payment date and a *payment method*
- Set the *bill* as *archived* with an archival date.

Thank you very much!